# Can we have the logicapps parameters spread across several files?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-logic-apps

I have a logicapps ARM template which also sends emails via an email connector, when the logicapp is running. I have included the HTML contents/body of the email inside the parameter json file, but I would prefer to put the body/content of the email into a separate file and import that into the parameter file at the time of deployment. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Did you mean you want to save the content in json file to a file? And which destination to save the file?FTP or One Drive or others?

Comment: Thanks George! I would like to keep the body of the email into a separate file instead of embedding the email body inside the parameter file. The email body is quite big, and it looks unclean to embed the content into the parameter file itself.
And the email content file can remain in the same folder i.e. parallel to the parameters file.

Comment: Maybe you could share more information like your flow pictures.

Comment: @GeorgeChen - well its simple; I simply want to place the contents/body of the email inside a separate file and I want to pull the contents of the file into the logic app ARM parameter/variable at the time of deployment. I hope it makes sense.
For e.g. the ARM file has the following entry:
"sendgrid_1_email_body_success": {
      "value": "The process was successful!!!"
    },

I only want to pull out the string "The process was successful!!!" and place the same into a separate text file and want the contents to be used at the time of deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You can host it in [blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage).